# The use of "that" in the sentence "what could I know, should I know, that I don’t know"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

> Like Lear, we can learn to see better, not just because our brain changes but because we do.
>   As all wisdom does, seeing starts with simple questions: What could I
>   know, should I know, **that** I don’t know?
>   From *"Wilful Blindness: Why We Ignore The Obvious"* by *Margaret Heffernan*
>  (quoted in multiple other books)

Can anyone tell me why in the last question, the "that" is necessary, what if replace it with "and"? so the sentence becomes "what could I know, (what) should I know, and (what) I don’t know?"

Comment: The grammar in that sentence isn’t exactly standard. It should rather be ‘What could I know and what should I know that I don’t know?’ Does that clear it up?

Comment: Notice that I've included the original source of your text. Please, add references. Context is important. Cheers!

Comment: The third phrase is not a question. If you want to turn it into a question, it would be "What don't I know?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your change doesn't produce equivalent phrases. You're changing the original intended meaning. The original author is proposing TWO questions not THREE.

Original

> Simple questions: What could I know, should I know, that I don’t know?

My interpretation

> Simple questions: What **could** I know that I don’t know? What **should** I know that I don't know?

You could introduce the conjuction between those two questions but not in the middle of one sentence.

> Simple questions: What could I know that I don’t know? **and** What should I know that I don't know?